# grid tags not working in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-material2

I am trying to create a grid layout in my Angular 2 based application with angular material2 but as i am trying to create a structure in the "app.component.html" file, the grid tags get an error that  **unknown html tags**. Here is the code of how i am trying to do it:
**app.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="game-area">
            <md-grid-list class="tick-tack-grid" cols="3">
                <md-grid-tile *ngFor="let block of gs.blocks; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn" (click)="playerClick(i)"><i [class]="block.symbol == 'done' ? 'material-icons tick' : 'material-icons cross'">{{ block.symbol }}</i></md-grid-tile>
            </md-grid-list>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from './Player';
import { Box } from './Box';
import { GameService } from './game.service';
...
```

Comment: did you import a module?

Comment: @ArturCzopek not in the html file but did it in the app component's typescript file

Comment: Can you provide the code to illustrate how you imported it?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten just added it to the question

Comment: You need to import it in your module as described in https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#the-root-appmodule

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten do you mean importing grid tags in "app.module.ts"? could your please elaborate a bit . i have already added all the imports according to the documentation

Comment: You need to import MdGridListModule in app.module.ts. See https://plnkr.co/edit/WervrHJXlcotb2tqNuGb?p=preview (main.ts). Did you do this?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten thanks! that solved the problem

Comment: Great, @RehanAziz. I've moved my solution to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you didn't import the MdGridListModule module in your application module. You need to do this:

```
import {
  MdGridListModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    MdGridListModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

See the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/WervrHJXlcotb2tqNuGb?p=preview) (main.ts) that illustrates this.